# ASP.Net ReportViewer control not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I am using Reportviewer control in my .aspx page. I set

```
  ReportViewer1.ShowPrintButton = false;
```

but it didn't work. Not only this button, i tried to show refresh button but it didn't work. thanks.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  if (!this.IsPostBack)
    PrintReport();
}
  private void PrintReport() {
    ReportViewer1.ShowPrintButton = false;
    ReportViewer1.ShowRefreshButton = false;
  }
```

Comment: please provide us with some more information. show us your aspx code as well as some code behind if necessary. what exactly did not work?

Comment: hi, here I provided code behind file details. Pls let me know if you need some more details.

Comment: ifyou mean this reportViewer class http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer(v=vs.80).aspx - this is a winForms control and it wont work on an aspx page...

Comment: Im talking about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running reports in remote mode in order for the buttons to work. In addition, if you want them to be shown, you have to set the values to True, not False as is shown in your code.

If you are running in local mode, there is an ActiveX control that can be downloaded, but this will only work for IE.

Here is a link to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251693.aspx) about printing from ReportViewer that should help you out.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to hide them. I have downloaded the control from here, started using it. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21916